# obtener el entero positivo menor que no este dentro del array

Tags: javascript, algoritmos

Hola estoy resolviendo el siguiente algortimo:

debo retornar el entero positivo mas pequeño que no se encuentre en el array el 0 no es tomado en cuenta ya que no se considera un entero  positivo...

esta es mi solucion

```
function solution(A) {
// ordenar
let arrSort = A.sort()

// tomar del array A sumarle uno a todos
let sumArr = arrSort.map((int) => {
    return int + 1;
});

// sacar los diferentes entre el array original y el de la suma
let dif = [];

for (let i of sumArr) {
    for (let j of arrSort) {
        if (i !== j) {
            dif.push(i);
        }
    }
}
return dif
```

}

tengo errores cuando quiero retonar los numero del array de i que no estan en j la salida esperad seria esta: [7,5] pero esto no sucede
alguien podria decirme que estoy haciendo mal.
de antemano gracias!

Comment: Edita tu pregunta y pon un ejemplo real para que se te entienda mejor

Answer (score 0):

Si no he entendido mal, se puede hacer de una forma mucho mas simple.

```
 const numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,7,8,9];

 function getNumber(array){
    let exists = true;
    let number = 0;
    do{
       number++;
       if(!array.includes(number)) exists = false;
    }while(exists)
    return number;
 }

 console.log(getNumber(numbers));
```

Comment: En el `if`, de dentro del `do`, te falta un paréntesis. Además de que estás tratando de cambiar el valor de `exists`, el cual es `const`, lo que significa que es constante y no se puede modificar... ¡CUIDADO!

Comment: Corrigiendo esos errores y por lo entendido en la pregunta, el resultado parece ser correcto.

Answer (score 0):

toma un algoritmo que encuentra el mas pequeño de los números y no toma en cuenta el 0 ni los negativos "agradecería tener más reputación en mi cuenta"

```
<script>
const numeros = [-2,-1,0,10,5,90];

const numeroSinNegativoNiCero = numeros.filter(num => num > 0)
let primerNumeroDeLaLista = numeroSinNegativoNiCero.find(num => num)
numeroSinNegativoNiCero.forEach(num => {
    if(primerNumeroDeLaLista>num){
        primerNumeroDeLaLista = num
    }
})
console.log(primerNumeroDeLaLista)


</script>
```

Comment: Se supone que no es el mas pequeño lo que busca, busca el número mas pequeño que NO esté presente en el array dado, pero además tiene que ser positivo y entero.

Answer (score -1):

Lo he solucionado realizando otra implementacion

```
function solution(A) {


let arr = A
let def = 1;



for (index of arr) {
    if (index < 1) {
        return def
    } else {
        // tomar del array A sumarle uno a todos
        let sumArr = arr.map((int) => {
            return int + 1;
        });

        // concatenando arrays
        let concat = arr.concat(sumArr);
        let exist = {},
            dif = [],
            number,
            output;

        for (index of concat) {
            number = index;
            if (!exist[number]) {
                dif.push(number)
                exist[number] = true;
            }
        }

        output = dif[dif.length - 1]
        return output

    }

}
```

Comment: Esta solución siempre va a devolver el último elemento + 1, cuando la pregunta dice "el entero positivo mas pequeño que no se encuentre en el array".